# Wide character input using fgetwc() and fread()

Tags: c, file-io, wchar-t

When reading a wide character from a `FILE` stream, can `fgetwc()` and `fread()` be used interchangeably?

It's tempting to assume that `fgetwc()` might work like this:

```c
wint_t fgetwc(FILE *src) {
  wchar_t c;
  size_t n_bytes = fread(&c, sizeof (wchar_t), 1, src);
  return (n_bytes == sizeof (wchar_t)) ? c : WEOF;
}
```

Although, I'm suspecting that such implementation might fail on big endian systems.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetwc` does not "read a wide character". It reads a *multibyte character* (these days, usually a UTF-8  sequence) and converts it into a `wchar_t`. Similarly, `fputwc` takes a `wchar_t` and writes it out as a multibyte sequence.

If you want to actually read or write `wchar_t` units, you need to use `fread` or  `fwrite`, and you should probably open the file in binary mode in case one of the bytes in the `wchar_t` would undergo special handling in a text file.

`fread` and `fwrite` are considered byte-oriented, so they cannot be mixed with wide-oriented I/O.

---

Note: apparently, the Windows library implementation of fgetwc and fputwc does read and write `wchar_t` units *if* the file was opened in binary mode. With files opened in text mode, the behaviour is as described above. See the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/unicode-stream-i-o-in-text-and-binary-modes?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

> can `fgetwc()` and `fread()` be used interchangeably?

Not easily.

---

Once a narrow or wide read/write occurs, the stream *orientation* is set to read *wide* or *narrow* characters.

`fread()` is a narrow function. Others: `fgetc, fgets, fprintf, fputc, fputs, fread, fscanf, fwrite, getc, getchar, printf, putc, putchar, puts, scanf, ungetc, vfprintf, vfscanf, vprintf, and vscanf`)

`fgetwc()` is a wide one. Others: `fgetws, getwc, getwchar, fwscanf, wscanf, vfwscanf, vwscanf, fputwc, fputws, putwc, putwchar, fwprintf, wprintf, vfwprintf, vwprintf`.

Use `fwide()` or `freopen()` to change the orientation.

Best not to mix narrow/wide functions else an error (*encoding*) may occur.

---

`endian` is a separate issue.  OP's `fgetwc()` does not take into account orientation nor certainly handle endian issues well.